# IllegalArgumentException occurs only sometimes in the app

Tags: android

I have found the following error in logcat when my app crashes. But I don't understand what the error actually means. If anyone knows please explain why these crashes occur. Moreover, the crashes occur sometime only.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@4052cd98
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:634)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:875)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
at android.widget.ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow(ViewFlipper.java:104)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6235)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1250)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1248)
at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1838)
at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2916)
at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2886)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:254)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:445)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3287)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1042)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's an `IllegalArgumentException`. From the looks of it, you probably haven't registered your `ViewFlipper` widget/receiver. Try adding it in your manifest if you haven't already done so. Please post your code so that it becomes clearer to figure out stuff.

Comment: have you used any progress dialog or any other dialog ??

Answer (score 1):

I saw this exact error reported from Android Market in an application I have developed. The problem, from what I can understand, actually comes from a bug in Android that sometimes happens when you change orientation while a ViewFlipper is visible (or, in rare cases, even when no ViewFlipper is visible). The bug is registered [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6191), and the discussion leads to a class called [SafeViewFlipper](http://pastie.org/1086467) that can be used instead of ViewFlipper. I have not released a version of my app with this fix, but from what I can read in the bug report and other places others have used it with great success.

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest file (Manifest.xml) you should add your `Receiver`.
If you are using Eclipse with the ADT plugin, open Manifest.xml and go to the `Application` tab.
Here you can add Activities, Services, Providers and Receivers.