# IllegalArgumentException in LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher()

Tags: android, apk

I have an Android application in android market, I am getting the following error report, 
I have used webView, zoom controls, these are all working fine, when ever I test it on OS 2.2,2.3,4.04,4.1,4.2. I don't know when this crash occur, either on zoom control or in loading .apk file from the market.
I am getting these error reports from several users, Please let me know what is this problem and how i can resolve this issue,

Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@43335900
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:628)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1178)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:361)
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.setVisible(ZoomButtonsController.java:405)
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$2.handleMessage(ZoomButtonsController.java:179)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is bug in ViewFlipper class.

See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8743449/2487367

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and successfully used this workaround:
[ViewFlipper : Receiver not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050730/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered/8208874#8208874)

You should basically create your own `ViewFlipper` subclass, and override it's `onDetachedFromWindow` function to stop flipping instead of crushing. 
Than use that subclass in your layout.